# 'HttpResponse' has no attribute '_get_content

Tags: django, django-piston

I am using Django 1.5.1 and Piston for rest support with MongoDB database.

When trying to test the rest url to retrieve the data, I get the following error.

```
type object 'HttpResponse' has no attribute '_get_content'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/annotation/search?limit=20&uri=/document
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'HttpResponse' has no attribute '_get_content'
Exception Location: /home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/utils.py in HttpResponseWrapper, line 72
Python Executable:  /home/tank/sites/python/env.example/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.4
```

The problem is generated in the piston code, not sure the reason. Here's the full traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/annotations/search?limit=20&uri=/templates

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'app.modules.members',
 'app.modules.cms',
 'app.modules.annotator',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py" in inner_func
  19.             response = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py" in __call__
  166.             result = self.error_handler(e, request, meth, em_format)
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py" in error_handler
  257.             result = rc.BAD_REQUEST
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/utils.py" in __getattr__
  51.         class HttpResponseWrapper(HttpResponse):
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/utils.py" in HttpResponseWrapper
  72.             content = property(HttpResponse._get_content, _set_content)            

Exception Type: AttributeError at /annotations/search
Exception Value: type object 'HttpResponse' has no attribute '_get_content'
```

/Thanks

New error trackback for 'HttpResponseWrapper' object has no attribute '_is_string' :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/annotations/search?limit=20&uri=

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'app.modules.members',
 'app.modules.cms',
 'app.modules.annotator',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py" in inner_func
  19.             response = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py" in __call__
  184.         if isinstance(result, HttpResponse) and not result._is_string:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /annotations/search
Exception Value: 'HttpResponseWrapper' object has no attribute '_is_string'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django 1.5 this code:

```
def _get_content(self):
    # do some stuff

def _set_content(self):
    # do some stuff

content = property(_get_content, _set_content)
```

was changed to:

```
@property
def content(self):
    # do some stuff

@content.setter
def content(self, value):
    # do some stuff
```

So, Django 1.5 doesn't have `_get_content` function. You should change `HttpResponseWrapper` in *piston/utils.py* to something like this:

```
class HttpResponseWrapper(HttpResponse):
    """
    Wrap HttpResponse and make sure that the internal
    _is_string/_base_content_is_iter flag is updated when the
    _set_content method (via the content property) is called
    """

    def _set_content(self, content):
        """
        Set the _container and _is_string /
        _base_content_is_iter properties based on the type of
        the value parameter. This logic is in the construtor
        for HttpResponse, but doesn't get repeated when
        setting HttpResponse.content although this bug report
        (feature request) suggests that it should:
        http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9403
        """
        is_string = False
        if not isinstance(content, basestring) and hasattr(content, '__iter__'):
            self._container = content
        else:
            self._container = [content]
            is_string = True
        if django.VERSION >= (1, 4):
            self._base_content_is_iter = not is_string
        else:
            self._is_string = is_string

    try:
        # Django versoin is older than 1.5

        content = property(HttpResponse._get_content, _set_content)

    except:
        # Django version 1.5

        @HttpResponse.content.setter
        def content(self, content):
            self._set_content(content)
```

Let me know if it works, I will commit this to `piston` code.

---

About the second issue: perhaps, your version is old. This issue was already solved in [this](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/3a0d021dd042/piston/resource.py) commit.

Comment: I get the following error: `'HttpResponseWrapper' object has no attribute '_is_string'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/annotations/search?limit=20&uri=
Django Version:  1.5.1
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'HttpResponseWrapper' object has no attribute '_is_string'

Exception Location:  /home/tank/sites/python/env.example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py in __call__, line 184`

Comment: @tank, Could you, please, add the new full traceback to the question?

Comment: I am using pip package manager to install piston. The version I have is django-piston (0.2.3), which seems to be the latest. Maybe the changes are in the master only. Anyways, the code above works.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by updating to the newest version of this piston fork:
https://github.com/marcio0/django-piston/